# Do American supermarkets have shopping cart conveyors or shopping cart coins?

Tags: usa, shopping

I recently saw a video of an American abroad who seemed quite astonished about things like <strike>shopping cart conveyors</strike> (edit: I have now learned that the correct term is "inclined moving walkway") or shopping cart coins (where shopping carts are locked unless you put a coin into them.)

It was quite entertaining because such devices have been totally commonplace for several decades where I live (inside EU).

Do such things not exist in the US?

Comment: In fairness, the person on that video also seemed impressed that the supermarket in question sold bread, so it's not like he is a particularly high intelligence person.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151622/discussion-on-question-by-jan-do-american-supermarkets-have-shopping-cart-convey); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Both exist, but are somewhat uncommon.

Shopping cart coins are used in the US, although it's retailer-dependent. It's not very common in most places, but some stores like Aldi often have them. Different stores have used them over the past several decades.

Shopping cart conveyors also exist in the US, but I might venture to say they're less common than in Europe. The vast majority of US supermarkets I've visited are on a single floor with an outdoor parking lot and simply have no need for a cart escalator. Only occasionally in large cities have I seen a second-floor supermarket, but they'll usually have a cart escalator if people are actually expected to move their cart between floors. It wouldn't be out of the question for an American to have never seen a cart conveyor, though, as many people outside cities wouldn't have ever seen a multi-level supermarket.

Comment: The **Target** in Albuquerque NM has a nice cart conveyor/escalator. (Too bad I don’t have a pic to share.)

Comment: Also the multi-story Targets in the San Fernando Valley of Los Angeles. Target, by the way, is more of a department store than a supermarket, although many do have a grocery section

Comment: Fun fact, if you look at the wikipedia article on shopping cart conveyors their example picture is actually in the US.

Comment: "some stores like Aldi often have them" ALDI is a German company, so it might be that it's simply part of their standard procedures.

Comment: @Dúthomhas I'm guessing you mean the Up Town shopping center in ABQ?

Comment: The only shopping cart/trolley conveyor I have ever seen in the UK is at my local IKEA in Bristol. Incidentally, I had to phone their central customer services line about something, and the (English) guy seemed friendly, so I asked him how his colleagues normally pronounced the name - whether they use the Swedish way or the British ('eye-keea') form. He said 'among ourselves we say it the original Swedish way but we change it for the Brits'.

Comment: @PeterM Yes. I'm back in southern NJ now, and there aren't any cool cart lifts here... ☹️

Comment: I don't know if this is common, but in my location in the US homeless people patrol the ALDI lots to return carts for people to keep the coin.  I've seen a fight break out over the rights to a lot before.  I'd be curious if it's similar nationwide and in Europe.

Comment: It should be mentioned that what Carlson was that surprised about was *not* a shopping cart conveyor or elevator. Just a regular moving walkway where both the floor and the shopping cart wheels have ridges that mesh and grip each other, so that the cart doesn't roll away as the walkway is inclined.

Answer (score 22):

For the downvoters: the answers to both questions are *yes, they do*. However there are reasons why they're much rarer in the US than in Europe.

If you disagree with the answer (the facts in it, not the existence of the writer which I know triggers some of you), feel free to leave a comment.

---

European/Asian supermarkets are built differently than American, and so is their currency systems.

In the US supermarkets are mostly flat single story very large buildings. Only in more urbanized areas where land is harder to get you'll see multi-storied supermarkets (I saw in New York, for example, or in the Bay Area), and those do have escalators often times. I used such an escalator in Target in a couple of places.

As to coins, in Europe there are high denomination coins. Don't know about Russia specifically, but in EUR zone you can get up to 2EUR denominations. Thus using coins as a security deposit is more meaningful enough for people to want to return their carts.

In the US the highest denomination of coins in circulation (not collectibles) is $1, but even that is rarely used and a lot of people don't even know it exists. I've never seen the $0.50 coin in circulation (although it technically exists), so the highest *actually* used is $0.25. Not a very big motivator. But yes, some stores do use them as security deposit as well.

In the US they also have, in many places, geo-barriers. Cart wheels lock up when taken beyond a certain perimeter on the parking lot. This is much more effective than a small and meaningless deposit against carts being stolen, while isn't onerous on the customers either.

The person you saw on TV (Tucker Carson) is a propagandist and is there to deliver the message "America is bad, Russia is good", so don't take it as a genuine amazement by something he's never seen before. Although I doubt he's been to any US supermarket any time recently either.

Comment: The highest denomination of coins in circulation in the Eurozone is 2€, higher denominations are collectibles only. The most common denomination used for shopping carts is 1€, though over the last decades, a lot of supermarkets have changed to systems allowing also 2€ and 0,50€. Especially the latter is hardly more of a motivator than $0.25 would be, so I don't think coin denominations are the main reason why cart coins are common in Europe but not in the US.

Comment: Large parking lots sounds more probable to me :). Plus, I have only been to a US supermarket 3 or 4 times in my life, they have always been somewhere near the highway, where you wouldn't have been able to walk the cart anywhere, whereas supermarkets in Germany are often right next to a residential area, which might also be a reason. Btw, german supermarkets usually have some 5-10 "return points" for shopping carts, there's not one single location to return the carts to.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151607/discussion-on-answer-by-littleadv-is-it-true-that-very-few-american-supermarkets); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Many shops in the Netherlands actually provide free non-currency coins to put in the shopping cart. Often with the ability to attach to your key chain, like [these](https://cdn.deschenker.nl/images/product/p1cbed3q351mhgn5014li1fa51v0qc.jpg). So it's not really about the denominations.

Comment: Folks, please see the moderator comment. If you still feel a really strong urge to leave a comment - please do so in the chat.

Comment: I've been under the impression that this coin trick is not here to prevent stealing the carts (a cart is far more expensive than 10 CZK after all), but to encourage people to return them to the area allotted for them rather than just leave them in the parking zone.

Comment: @ach I agree. Shopping carts are expensive enough that there are vans which go around picking them up from wherever people have left them around town miles from any supermarket. If there was lots of parking space, it wouldn't matter if the trolleys were left scattered, but when every space is used it would be a nuisance to have to get out of your car to move a trolley that's in the way.

Comment: The money value is not to recover the cost of stolen cart, after all - the cart would be stolen with the coin in it. The money is to encourage people to return the cart to position and recover their coin.

Comment: @Ivo Can you explain what the point of that is?  Why require a coin at all in that scenario?

Comment: @sabine I don't think coin carts are common in Canada either and they have loonies and twonies which, if I am correct, would suggest denominations are not a factor.

Comment: @JimmyJames even if the coin is worthless in terms of monetary value people still value to have that coin in their possession (to use it again another time to get another shopping cart). Having to ask for a new coin every time is an inconvenience that people don't want to have. Also, if a store notices that the same person keeps requesting a new coin all the time I'm sure they will tell them at some point to stop doing it. In any case, it works. Carts are returned 100% of the time, with some exceptions.

Comment: @Ivo If the carts are generally returned and the coin has no value, maybe there's no need for a coin at all?

Answer (score 10):

> Do American supermarkets have shopping cart conveyors or shopping cart coins?

Some do. Here is an example of shopping cart coins at an [Aldi store](https://maps.app.goo.gl/iQzm3Cp7SSGsEqoM6) near Los Angeles:

[image]

(Author: [Alessio Sangalli](https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/110222110623604494759))

Shopping cart conveyors are also present in the US, e.g. see this [video](https://youtu.be/0-0PLhyy3_k) or this report: Eadie, Tisha (February 1, 2005). ["Shopping Carts Used At Multi-Level Retailers? An Impossibility No More!"](https://web.archive.org/web/20160303234652/http://www.elevator-world.com/files/feb05.pdf). Elevator World. Elevator World, Inc.: 61–63.

> It was quite entertaining

Acting ignorant to get more views.

Comment: Aldi is german firm (in Germany called **Aldi Süd**), so it should be no surprise that they use the same cart system. Originaly a 1 DM coin was used.

Comment: Aldi süd may use the coin-locked carts, but I haven't seen them at other german-owned supermarkets in the US. Theo Albricht (owner of Aldi Nord) owned Trader Joe's since 1979 and they do not use coin-locked carts, nor does lidl in my experience.

Comment: @MarkJohnson it's not called Aldi Süd in Germany, just Aldi. While technically the company that owns all stores is called that the stores themselves are just called Aldi just like in the US.

Comment: @Ivo The logo itsself contains the word **Süd** (The logo for Aldi Nord contains only Aldi without Nord). Just because most peaple leave out the Nord/Süd in everyday coversations, doesn't change the name of the company. [Aldi – Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aldi) and [Das Aldi-Logo: Darum wirkt es auf uns so "billig", aber erinnerungswürdig - wmn](https://www.wmn.de/buzz/aldi-logo-wirkung-supermarkt-einkaufen-werbung-marke-id282397)